# How can I show a tabular list of variables and their values?

Tags: variables

Is there a way to see the values of a list of variables? E.g., if I have `var1`, `var2` and `var3`, is there a standard `elisp` function that shows me the values of these variables at the same time?

I mean something that returns an output like:

```
var1   nil
var2   t
var3   nil
```

I don't need the output to be a string. I just need to read it in a window.

Please note that I asked if is there an emacs standard function that already does it. Otherwise every help is welcome but I can also try to do it by myself.

Comment: By "returns an output like..." do mean you want the function to return a string with the values formatted as you specified? Or do you want the function to insert this in a buffer perhaps? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Aquaactress I updated my question. Thank you for pointing this detail.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant function is `symbol-value`.

According to its documentation:

```
symbol-value is a function defined in C source code.

Signature
(symbol-value SYMBOL)

Documentation
Return SYMBOL's value.  Error if that is void.

Note that if lexical-binding is in effect, this returns the
global value outside of any lexical scope.
```

This is an example of using it on a list of variables.

```
(mapcar #'symbol-value '(emacs-version emacs-build-time evil-undo-system))
;;=> ("27.1 nil nil)
```

EDIT:

I copied your desired ouput and wrote a function which returns a string. Not that we need to use unique symbols so we avoid the possibility of running into scope problems (when a variable you want to print has the same name as the parameter of the lambda).

```
(defun my/tabular-values (variable-list)
  (let ((var (gensym "var")))
    (mapc `(lambda (,var)
         (thread-last (symbol-value ,var)
           (format "%S %S\n" ,var)
           (insert)))
      variable-list)))

(let ((var1 nil)
      (var2 t)
      (var3 nil))
  (my/tabular-values '(var1 var2 var3)))

;; The following is inserted into buffer after using `eval-print-last-sexp`.

var1   nil
var2   t
var3   nil
```

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: I can easily use your code to write a function that shows the values in a temp buffer. I'll wait to see if other answers come. Otherwise I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Your function suffers from the same problem that the function in my answer suffers: try changing `var3` to `var` in the the `let` form (in both places).

Comment: Could use a UUID in place of `var` in function :-)  `uuid | sed -e 's/-//g'  -e 's/^/uuid/`

Comment: @NickD I don't understand. Could you elaborate? What problem was that?

Comment: @alls0rts I don't understand. Is using a UUID better?  Could you show an example this being done?

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, the issue is that var outside of the function is not displayed as `var` inside the function is in scope. 

```
(defun my/tabular-values (variable-list)
  (mapc (lambda (uuid0f163ba0715011eba0b733df45ff27cb)
   (insert (format "%S   %S\n" uuid0f163ba0715011eba0b733df45ff27cb
     (symbol-value uuid0f163ba0715011eba0b733df45ff27cb))))
    variable-list))

```

Comment: ... which runs into trouble if I have a variable in the surrounding scope named `uuid0f163ba0715011eba0b733df45ff27cb`. Basically, the function lacked referential transparency. BTW, the edited function gives me an error: ` (void-variable var1)` - not sure who is at fault yet: I may be doing something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight elaboration of [Aquaactress' answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/63433/14825) that uses an Org mode code block to produce a table. It uses `-zip-with` from the [dash package](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el).

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (setq x 'foo y 'bar z 'baz)

  (setq l '(x y z))

  (-zip-with #'list (mapcar #'symbol-name l) (mapcar #'symbol-value l))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| x | foo |
| y | bar |
| z | baz |
```

BTW, I tried producing the pairs with a function and failed miserably:

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (setq x 'foo y 'bar z 'baz)

  (setq l '(x y z))

  (defun symbol-name-value (x)
    (list (symbol-name x) (symbol-value x)))

  (mapcar #'symbol-name-value l)

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| x | x   |
| y | bar |
| z | baz |
```

The failure is obvious in retrospect, but I don't know how to fix it.